# QtCreator CMake Project Auto-Complete Not Always Working?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2013

I have been working on a project that uses cmake as the build system and working in QtCreator just fine. There are sub-projects (some Qt related and others just plain c++) and up until now all of them were able to find header files and hence provide auto-complete functionality.

At some point, I added a Qt project and noticed that my headers for Qt proejcts were not being found by the editor. The really odd thing is they compile and run just fine via QtCreator 'Build->Build All'. It is almost like QtCreator just can't find them for auto-complete.

I looked around and users had problems in earlier versions of QtCreator finding Qt classes, but did not seem to have a problem finding their defined header files.

I put together a simplified "project" and added two fresh Qt Widget Application projects with the main window being a QDialog instead of QMainWindow. I added the following CMakeLists.txt file to each project:

```
My Standard CMake File For Qt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project("FooProj")
set(EXECUTABLE_NAME "Foo")

# Find Qt packages.
find_package(Qt5Core)
find_package(Qt5Widgets)
find_package(Qt5Gui)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)


set(SOURCES 
    "src/main.cpp"
    "src/Dialog.cpp"
)

set(HEADERS
    "includes/Dialog.h"
)

set(UI_FORMS
    "forms/Dialog.ui"
)

set(RESOURCES_FILES
    "resources/resources.qrc"
)

# Convert Qt UI and resource files to C/C++ files.
qt5_wrap_ui(UI_HEADERS ${UI_FORMS})
qt5_add_resources(RESOURCES ${RESOURCES_FILES})


# Define the executable to be built.
add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} 
    ${SOURCES}
    ${HEADERS}
    ${UI_HEADERS}
    ${RESOURCES}
)

# Include paths for this project.
target_include_directories(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} PRIVATE
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/includes"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
)

# Link to appropriate libraries.
target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME}
    Qt5::Core
    Qt5::Widgets
    Qt5::Gui
)


# Set distribution location and project structure.
set(DIST_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/dist/${EXECUTABLE_NAME}")
set_property(TARGET ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} PROPERTY FOLDER "Guis")


# Setup distribution environment and copy final executable.
add_custom_command(TARGET ${EXECUTABLE_NAME}
  POST_BUILD
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${DIST_DIR}
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy $<TARGET_FILE:${EXECUTABLE_NAME}> ${DIST_DIR}
)

# OS specific deployment setup for sytems without Qt installed.
if(WIN32)
  add_custom_command(TARGET ${EXECUTABLE_NAME}
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/QtDeploymentFiles/run.bat" ${DIST_DIR}/${EXECUTABLE_NAME}.bat
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/QtDeploymentFiles/qt.conf" ${DIST_DIR}
  )

elseif(UNIX AND NOT APPLE)
  add_custom_command(TARGET ${EXECUTABLE_NAME}
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/QtDeploymentFiles/run.sh" ${DIST_DIR}/${EXECUTABLE_NAME}.sh
  )
endif()
```

Along with this top level CMakeLists.txt:

```
Top Level CMakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project("Test")

add_subdirectory("FooProj")
add_subdirectory("BarProj")
```

Everything makes, compiles, and runs just fine. Auto-complete also works.

I add a Qt library project I need and everything still works fine even when I use the library files. Here is the cmake file for my library:

```
Qt Library CMakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project("QtLib")
set(LIB_NAME "QtLib")

# Find Qt packages.
find_package(Qt5Core)
find_package(Qt5Widgets)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

# Set source files to be built.
set(SOURCES
    "src/LibFile1.cpp"
    "src/LibFile2.cpp"
    .
    .
    .
)

set(HEADERS
    "includes/LibFile1Header.h"
    "includes/LibFile2Header.h"
    "includes/OtherHeaders.h"
    .
    .
    .
)

add_library(${LIB_NAME} ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})

set_property(TARGET ${LIB_NAME} PROPERTY FOLDER "Libs")

target_include_directories(${LIB_NAME} PRIVATE
    "${Qt5Core_INCLUDE_DIRS}"
    "${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS}"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
)
target_include_directories(${LIB_NAME} PUBLIC
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/includes"
)


target_link_libraries(${LIB_NAME}
    Qt5::Core
    Qt5::Widgets
)
```

Lastly I add one of my real projects (one of the ones that does not auto-complete) The structure is as follows:

```
-forms
    -MainForm.ui
-resources
    -resources.qrc
    -resource files and dirs
-src
    -main.cpp
    -MainWindow.cpp
-includes
    -MainWindow.h
```

The CMake file is exactly the same as the ones above. Everything makes, compiles, and runs just fine, but auto-complete stops working. I also noticed that ui_MainWindow.h (the one being auto-generated in my project binary directory) is not found.

The really odd thing is, if I just the exact same files with no changes and just open it as a stand alone project, auto-complete works.

Is there something off about my cmake files or is this a Qt related issue? The same thing happens in VS2013 which makes me think it is not QtCreator related, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

After reading around a little more, it seemed like this might be a QtCreator issue (although I don't know why I had problems in VS2013 when I first tested it). I ended up upgrading my QtCreator to 3.6 and my auto-complete problem went away.